# Range(cells).visiblecells selecting the whole sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using variable references for selecting a filtered range in a loop and having some hard time when the range references become same. When it becomes same the code is selecting the whole sheet. I'm unable to solve this.
Here's my code

```
For tor = 11 To 17 ' for selecting the column
  .UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=tor, Criteria1:="Yes"
  coot = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
  If coot > 1 Then ' stuck here when coot becomes 2 code is selecting the whole sheet
  Set yesrng = .Range(Cells(2, tor), Cells(coot,tor)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
  yesrng.Select
  end if
Next tor
```

If row value is 2
[image]
if row value is anything other than 2
[image]

Comment: Can you provide a snap shot of your worksheet? it will help to understand the problem a bit more

Comment: @Zac pic added as per request.

Comment: Do you have a hidden row at the top?

Comment: @Zac,there are no hidden rows.

Comment: Sorry for my bad explanation. I've done enough research before posting this question.

Comment: Can you change your `coot` assignment to `coot = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).End(xlUp).Row` and try it? I think problem might be that although you have a filter on, you are still getting the row count of all rows and not just the ones visible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you try to apply `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` to a single cell that is not visible it just takes the whole sheet. You could check if your range is single cell:

```
Dim wholeRng As Range
Set wholeRng = .Range(Cells(2, tor), Cells(coot,tor))
If wholeRng.Cells.Count = 1 Then
    If wholeRng.EntireRow.Hidden = True Then
        Set yesrng = Nothing
    Else
        Set yesrng = wholeRng
    End If
Else
    Set yesrng = wholeRng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
End If
```

However you also run into a problem if you apply `SpecialCells` to a multi cell range that has no visible cells (you'll get an error 1004 something like "No cells were found"). You can use an error handler (or just ignore the error)

```
'...
Set yesrng = Nothing 'so you'll know if it worked
On Error Resume Next 'ignore errors
Set yesrng = wholeRng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
On Error Goto 0 'reactivate default error handling!
'...
```

Then always check `If yesrng Is Nothing` afterwards! The nicer way would be to check the error number but since 1004 is a pretty generic error it wouldn't help much.

Comment: @arcadeprecinct The cell is visible,please check the image added now.I want to select only range between K2:K2.visible cells.The Reason for this  is the loop that I used remains same for 5 columns.The problem only comes when row value becomes 2.If row value is anything other than 2 the code works as expected.

Comment: If the row value is 2, your range is only one cell. When I tested it the issue appeared only when that cell was hidden but I might be wrong. Handling the special case of one cell independently should still work?

Comment: Thanks for the help @arcadeprecinct.I will add your code.